# is there a way to add information through pure php in modal? using bootstrap 3

Tags: php

I was trying to add some information in my database but I'm using bootstrap modal... can I achieve this using only php?

here's my html code.

```
    <form class = "form-horizontal" method = "post">
                    <div class = "modal-body">
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label for = "contact-name" class = "col-lg-2 control-label">Name: </label>
                            <div class = "col-lg-10">
                                <input type = "text" name = "fullname" placeholder = "Full name.." class = "form-control" id  = "contact-name"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label for = "contact-email"  class = "col-lg-2 control-label">Email: </label>
                            <div class = "col-lg-10">
                                <input type = "email" name = "email" placeholder = "you@example.com" class = "form-control" id  = "contact-email"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label for = "contact-msg" class = "col-lg-2 control-label">Message: </label>
                            <div class = "col-lg-10">
                                <textarea class = "form-control" rows = "8" name = "message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "modal-footer">
                        <a class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a>
                        <input type = "submit" name = "cmd_contact" class ="btn btn-primary" value = "Send"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

here is my php code for adding the information...

```
    $dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "bootstrap";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Could not open database");

    if(isset($_POST['cmd_contact']))
    {
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $query ="INSERT INTO contact_us (`fullname`, `email`, `message`) VALUES ('$fullname', '$email', '$message')";

    mysql_query($query);
    }
?>
```

Comment: So what would you like to do?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? how does your php code look like?

Comment: what I want is when I clicked the submit button there... I want it to add those 3 information in my database.... can I do it using php only?..

Comment: @winner_joiner thanks for editing my code sir.. appreciate it!

Comment: sorry again guys.... it was my mistake... the file should be in .php not .html/.htm..

Comment: Yes, that is what PHP does. It's a server side scripting language which you can use to add information to your database, even if the form is within a BootStrap modal. The page will refresh when you submit the form. Also, please look into MySQLi or PDO prepared statements. You are using the old mysql_* functions which are now deprecated and insecure. http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/